# Pick random image from an existing folder

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to make the controller randomly pick an image and assign it, even though I have been having some trouble with it. I noticed my code is only getting one image after 3 tries.

Here is my code:

```
$imagesDir = 'subjectImgs/';
        $images = glob($imagesDir . '*.{jpg,jpeg,png,gif}', GLOB_BRACE);
        $icon = $images[array_rand($images)];
        $subject = new Subject([
        'user_id' => auth()->user()->id, 
        'name' => $request->name,
        'icon' => $icon,
        ]);
```

Comment: Do you folder has more than one image? :)

Comment: Yes, it does :)

Comment: It doesn't return the same image for me every time. Maybe you're caching it?

Comment: Never tell me the odds... out from 20 images I got the same one 3 times, haha. I'll have to add more images then.